# Implement async await using angular.forEach in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, async-await, deferred

I am trying to save the tags for selected items list using api. In api I store the tags only once for the first selected item and for the rest I do not store the items instead I create the entry as shared.
Problem is: the first selected item hits the api and before storing the data other selected items also gets hit and I am not able to provide the shared reference as the data is not been stored yet.

Things I have tried -

This is my controller:

```
let selectedQstCount = $scope.selectedQuestion.length;
for (i = 0; i < selectedQstCount; i++) {
    var params = {
        "jsonString": callbackData,
        "questionNo": $scope.Questionlst.find(a => a.QuestionId == $scope.selectedQuestion[i].id).QuestionNo,
        "projectName": $scope.ProjectName,
        "projectId": $scope.ProjectId,
        "questionId": $scope.selectedQuestion[i].id,
        "newCodeFrame": ($scope.attachCodeFrame == "No" ? "FALSE" : "TRUE"),
        "sharedQstId": $scope.sharedQstId,
        "groupName": $scope.groupName
    }
    var defer = $q.defer();
    CodeFrameJsonfactory.CodeFrameUpload(params, function (data) {
        //success
        $q.resolve(data);
    }, function (callbackData) {
        //error
        inform.clear();
        inform.add(callbackData.Message, { ttl: -1, type: 'danger' });
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

This is my factory:

```
CodeFrameUpload: function (params, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: APIUrls.getUrl("uploadCodeFrame"),
        data: params,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        cache: false
    }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
        successCallback(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        deferred.reject(data);
        errorCallback(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

I have also tried using angular.forEach with deffered.

I want achieve is, until CodeFrameUpload function is completed I do not want to hit it again.

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 0):

Return a data promise:

```
CodeFrameUpload: function (params) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: APIUrls.getUrl("uploadCodeFrame"),
        data: params,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        cache: false
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
},
```

Map the returned promises:

```
var promiseArr = $scope.selectedQuestion.map(question => {
    var params = {
        "jsonString": callbackData,
        "questionNo": $scope.Questionlst.find(a => a.QuestionId == question.id).QuestionNo,
        "projectName": $scope.ProjectName,
        "projectId": $scope.ProjectId,
        "questionId": question.id,
        "newCodeFrame": ($scope.attachCodeFrame == "No" ? "FALSE" : "TRUE"),
        "sharedQstId": $scope.sharedQstId,
        "groupName": $scope.groupName
    }
    return CodeFrameJsonfactory.CodeFrameUpload(params);
});
```

Use `$q.all`:

```
$q.all(promiseArr).then(function(dataArr) {
    console.log(dataArr);
}).catch(function(errResponse) {
    console.log(errResponse);
});
```

`$q.all` returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

---

### Update

The above example executes the HTTP requests in parallel.

### To chain promises sequentially:

```
var paramsArr = $scope.selectedQuestion.map(question => ({
        "jsonString": callbackData,
        "questionNo": $scope.Questionlst.find(a => a.QuestionId == question.id).QuestionNo,
        "projectName": $scope.ProjectName,
        "projectId": $scope.ProjectId,
        "questionId": question.id,
        "newCodeFrame": ($scope.attachCodeFrame == "No" ? "FALSE" : "TRUE"),
        "sharedQstId": $scope.sharedQstId,
        "groupName": $scope.groupName
}));

var sequentialPromise = paramsArr.reduce( (promise, paramsObj) => {
    promise.then(function(dataArr) {
        var singlePromise = CodeFrameJsonfactory.CodeFrameUpload(paramsObj);
        return $q.all([...dataArr, singlePromise]);
    },
    $q.when([])
);

sequentialPromise.then(function(dataArr) {
    console.log(dataArr);
});
```

Comment: I think .map .forEach is not the right way to call the ajax in sync. It is hitting the api all at once. There has to be some other way round.

Comment: Updated the answer to show an example of chaining sequential promises.